# Asp.Net Core MVC: Unable to configure routing using Areas

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to configure Mvc routes using Areas.

This is the simplest version of my attempts.

**Demo Controller**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace SampleApp.Controllers
{
    [Area("Demo")]
    public class DemoController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("hello")]
        public string Hello() => "Hello Guest";
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "demo_area",
                areaName: "Demo",
                template: "super/demo/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Demo", action = "Hello" });

        });
    }
```

---

I've also implemented a Debug controller to examine the router that returns the following route definition:

```
{
    "action": "Hello",
    "controller": "Demo",
    "dataTokens": null,
    "defaults": null,
    "name": null,
    "template": "hello" // -> Get http://localhost:5000/hello
}
```

Comment: What sort of problem are you having?  Are your routes working at all?  If you want to use the area in the route, what happens if you try this: 
`template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action}`

Comment: It seems that MapAreaRoute doesn’t produce any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it** (and very disappointed).

Reading again the routing documentation there's a clear statement: «conventional and attribute based routing cannot be mixed». In these cases the latter wins.

I was wrong using the `HttpGet`attribute.

**Edit**

I've done some work to overcame this limitation. I'm not aware of an equivalent easy solution provided by the framework.

I've implemented a simple `RouteModuleAttribute` and an `IRouteBuilder` extension method that interact to provide the requested behaviour.

The full solution, which is *out of scope* for this thread, is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MrBogomips/MrBogomips.AspNetMvc.ModuleRouting).